# Robinson R22/44/66 Headset Plug For Bose A20 Headset

Tags: aircraft-systems

What type of headset connector plug is used on R22/44/66 Helicopters?
Is Bose A20 Headset a good one to be used on helicopter?

Answer (score 2):

Helicopters use a U-174/U or U-93A/U single-plug headset connector. Most aviation headsets come with PJ-068 & PJ-055B or equivalent. You will need an adapter. The second part of your question calls for an opinion, which is out of scope for this service.

Comment: All helicopters, even those of GA?

Comment: You need an electret mic with an R22 headset IIRC @IvanObodovsky, you'd need to check to make it has one, other than that I agree it's opinion based.

Comment: Yes, all including GA. That's the standard for helos.